# limit time per move

Tags: c

I make a simple game where I need to limit time for player's reflection.

For example, pseudo code for 10 seconds timer

```
int player = 0;
while(1){
    int time = 0;

    *time increases*
    *player should choose his letter*

    if(*player does nothing for 10 seconds*){
        player = !player;
        continue;
    }
}
```

I have no idea how to implement this in my code and asking for advice

Comment: What exactly is the question? You can get the elapsed time either via standard library functions such as `time` or `clock` or, if you need higher precisions, via system specific functions

Comment: In standard C in a single thread, it is not possible as standard I/O functions are blocking and do not have timeouts. You can do it if you create the thread which reads the user input and use IPC mechanisms like queues, mutexes, or semaphores.

Comment: @UnholySheep can you show me how to use it to limit the time `scanf` is waiting for input.

Comment: @0___________ there was no mention of `scanf` in the question, but that's a good point, since OP didn't specify how the user input should be read

Comment: @UnholySheep Standard C. scanf, fgets - whatever.

Comment: You cannot do this with standard C, but most platforms provide some sort of timer for a variant of `select` or `epoll` or `poll`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this in standard C, but most (probably all) platforms will provide some mechanism to do this.  You can't do it directly with `scanf`, but you can wait until data is available before calling `scanf`.  For example:

```
/* Set a 10 second timer on a scanf */

#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int
main(void)
{
    struct timeval tp = {.tv_sec = 10, .tv_usec = 0};
    char b[32];
    fd_set fds;

    FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &fds);
    switch( select(STDIN_FILENO + 1, &fds, NULL, NULL, &tp) ){
    case 1:
        if( FD_ISSET(STDIN_FILENO, &fds) ){
            if( scanf("%31s", b) == 1 ){
                printf("Read: %s\n", b);
            }
        }
        break;
    case 0:
        puts("Timeout");
        break;
    default:
        fputs("Error\n", stderr);
    }

}
```